# json data manipulation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two sets of data in JSON format:

data1

```
{
  "c_u0": [
    {
      "en_name": "akamai app external-dfgt",
      "en_id": 446,
      "spur": {
        "spcg": [
          {
            "a_id": 234,
            "b_id": "e_id from data2 to be inserted here",
            "cls": [
              {
                "address": "{\"fgt\":\"Cc\",\"Ik\":\"01\",\"IV_Y\":\"CP1\",\"IID\":\"0054\",\"IY\":1,\"SL\":\"https://ap.com\",\"OC\":\"\"}",
                "cl_id": 456103,
                "type": "SC",
                "name": "SFTPC",
                "srt": "sdp%",
                "oner": "ar"
              }
            ],
            "adata": false
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "en_name": "Aakle-akamai",
      "en_id": 444,
      "spur": {
        "spcg": [
          {
            "a_id": 456,
            "b_id": "e_id from data2 to be inserted here",
            "cls": [
              {
                "address": "{\"fgt\":\"Cc\",\"Ik\":\"01\",\"IV_Y\":\"CP1\",\"IID\":\"0054\",\"IY\":1,\"SL\":\"https://ap.com\",\"OC\":\"\"}",
                "cl_id": 4545673,
                "type": "SG",
                "name": "SMC",
                "srt": "sdfe",
                "oner": "agtr"
              }
            ],
            "adata": false
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "en_name": "APLOI - Zedgede",
      "en_id": 48946,
      "spur": {
        "spcg": [
          {
            "a_id": 47654,
            "b_id": "e_id from data2 to be inserted here",
            "cls": [
              {
                "address": "{\"fgt\":\"Cc\",\"Ik\":\"01\",\"IV_Y\":\"CP1\",\"IID\":\"0054\",\"IY\":1,\"SL\":\"https://ap.com\",\"OC\":\"\"}",
                "cl_id": 456178803,
                "type": "SjC",
                "name": "SFTPd",
                "secret": "sdpb%",
                "owner": "arb"
              }
            ],
            "adata": false
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

data2

```
[
  {
    "en_name": "Aakle-akamai",
    "eid": 1111
  },
  {
    "en_name": "Appg - ies"
  },
  {
    "en_name": "c console",
    "e_id": 1131
  },
  {
    "en_name": "akamai app external- dfgt",
    "e_id": 1122
  }
]
```

I am trying to check if `en_name` in data1 and data2 matches or not. On a match then do the following:

1. Create another mapped dataset(dict) as data3 that will have two elements. A complete `spcg` array from data1 and `e_id` from data2.
2. Replace the default value of key `b_id` (e_id from data2 to be inserted here) in `spcg` array with matched `e_id` from data2.

Here is what I have tried and the same doesnt even match the `en_name` .
No clue on how to achieve this specially the second one as I am not very expert in python

```
ab=[]
cd=[]
for keyt in data1:
    temp=data1['en_name']
    for keyz in data2:
        if temp == keyz['en_name']:
             ab.append(keyz['e_id'])
             cd.append(key['spcg'])
data3 =[{'e_name': b, 'spcg': l} for b, l in zip(ab, cd)]
```

Any help would be great

Comment: When working with JSON data you can make it much easier by using a library, such as [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) which is included in the standard library

Comment: @KJTHoward Yes I went through the same know but how that would help here can you elaborate?

Comment: Just checked the link and `data1` is not a valid JSON string.

Comment: What is the reason for not simply pasting here the json strings as text?

Comment: @accdias Changed the same and updated in the question one comma was missing thanks for pointing out

Comment: @SergeBallesta Updated the correct json in question as you edited, thanks. I was just thinking it would be too big post out here that was the reason to have it in another link

Comment: `data1` is still invalid JSON. I guess it is better to run it through a lint before posting.

Comment: `json.loads()` is complaining about `data1` but `jq` lint seems to find it fine. :-/

Comment: `json.loads()` ? or it would be `json.load()`

Comment: _Here is what I have tried and the same doesnt even match the en_name_ Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @AMC question is clear to lot of contributors in stack overflow and the issue is resolved , thanks for putting the negative vote to a new member and to the question which has a right answer as well.

Comment: @John _question is clear to lot of contributors in stack overflow_ Well unfortunately it isn't clear to me where the problem actually stems from, and whether this will be relevant to future readers, or at least more relevant than the thousands of questions like it. _and to the question which has a right answer as well_ Having an answer which works is good, and I'm glad one was found, but it isn't the only thing that matters, right?

Comment: @AMC you are 100 percent right in your opinion :-) but unfortunately my opinion differs, the question can be helpful to lot of people who are looking for same scenario, and yes this has got a working answer as well. As i read through the stackoverflow community everyone is trying to help here and ofcourse with different opinions.

Comment: _the question can be helpful to lot of people who are looking for same scenario_ Sorry if I wasn't clear, my point is that these sorts of questions, of which there are many, are only relevant to the precise situation their author is in. They're all just a matter of knowing basic dictionary manipulation. I will try to find a canonical/reference answer, although I'm not sure if there is one.

Comment: Thanks for finding one :-) and your help here. bdw curios question -- how do you know that someone will not have the same scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use built in **`json — JSON encoder and decoder`** library in python. This library simplifies handling of `json` files.

Here is the code you might want to try:

```
import json

data3 = []
with open("data1.json", "r") as f1:
    data1 = json.load(f1)
    with open("data2.json", "r") as f2:
        data2 = json.load(f2)
        for item1 in data1["c_u0"]:
            for item2 in data2:
                if item1["en_name"] == item2["en_name"]:
                    spcg = item1["spur"]["spcg"]
                    eid = item2["eid"]

                    for sp in spcg:
                        sp["b_id"] = eid # substitute the b_id with eid

                    data3.append({ "spcg": spcg, "e_id": eid})

print(data3)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Somehow it is not matching the names correctly as expected
`en_name": "akamai app external- dfgt` should also be matched according to the desired output but it only matches  `en_name": "Aakle-akamai`

Comment: @John that's because they are different in your json files, check again there is a extra space after `-` in `data2.json`

Comment: Will it only exactly match the names if both are same with respect to spacing and all ?

Comment: Yes. For strings to match they should contain same chars.

Comment: You could try `item2["en_name"].replace('- ', '-')` while comparing.

Comment: Why not have have both calls to `open()` in the same context manager?